# Return value based on most recent "completed year"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data that lists a Term Year ("A", "B", "C", ...) and some data.

A term year is a complete calendar year from that includes all 12 months.

I am trying to determine the most recent, complete, term year with a formula.  (Not a UDF if possible).

Example data:

```
Term    Month      Year  Misc. Data
A      January     2017  32
A      February    2017  35
A      March       2017  448
A      April       2017  747
A      May         2017  656
A      June        2017  370
A      June        2017  1892
A      July        2017  373
A      August      2017  387
A      August      2017  3
A      August      2017  32992
A      September   2017  815
A      October     2017  479
A      November    2017  753
A      December    2017  413
B      August      2018  544
B      September   2018  541
B      October     2018  435
B      November    2018  17
B      December    2018  270
B      January     2018  309
B      February    2018  488
```

(Edit: Added data, there will be multiple entries per month.)

So, since Term A is the most recent from today (being 2019) that has all months , I am just looking to have the formula return `A`.

As for my current attempts, I can't think of how to work an `Index/Match` formula. I am "afraid" I'll need a UDF, or at least some type of helper column.  So far I've gotten just `=Index(A2:A20` but can't think of how to build it from there.  I have a hunch `Aggregate()` may be needed but I can't figure how.

Comment: Is the month column a string or a custom format of a date value? - Are you looking to handle this by a single formula or can we knock up a named range / table of month names (or would unique number of `Month` results be adequate instead)

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor - The Terms are all Strings.  Month column is also a String, but we can change around if it helps.  A single formula would be nice, but not required.  I am okay with a helper table, but if the solution is a mix of say three formulas, a lookup table, etc. then I might opt for a UDF.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you only have a single entry per month, and **IF** the years are sorted ascending as you show, then try:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIFS(Table1[Year],Table1[Year])=12),Table1[[#All],[Term]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the formula Ron! I edited my question, there will be multiple entries per month.  However, I can probably just filter the data out to get just one entry per month, and use this formula.

Comment: @BruceWayne I'll think about a formula.  But, depending on your desired end-product, you could consider a pivot table with Rows for the years and `Distinct Count` of Months for the values.  You'd have to refresh and refer to the Pivot table column to get your results if data changed, though.

Comment: Good idea!  Generally, I'm trying to just do some analysis on the most recent FULL year.  So I'm just basically trying to ask Excel "What is the most recent term that has  all months?" - I just need a date and can work from there. (Full disclosure - haven't had the chance to try your formula yet, should by tomorrow).